# How to pass multiple forms as parameter in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

`(1/1) ErrorException
Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\priceDetails::finalSubmit() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given`

Error I'm getting while passing multiple parameters with controller function.

**Ajax code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#finalSubmit').click(function() {
      var form1 = $('#priceform').serialize();
      var form2 = $('#formdescription').serialize();
      var form3 = $('#additionaldescription').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url:"{{url('dbvalue')}}",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {form1: form1, form2: form2, form3: form3},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Laravel route:

```
Route::get('dbvalue','priceDetails@finalSubmit');
```

Controller:

```
 public function finalSubmit(Request $priceform,Request $formdescription)
 {      
   $var1 = $this->addPriceDetails($priceform);
   $var2 = $this->addProductDetails($formdescription);
   $var3 = $this->addAdditionalInformation($additionaldescription);
   $var4 = $this->addImages($imagesform);
   echo("success");
 }
```

This what I'm trying to give multiple form parameters in laravel controller function.

**addPriceDetails fn:**

```
public function addPriceDetails(Request $priceform)
{
$priceInfo = new priceInfo ;

$priceInfo->id=$this->getpriceDetailsId();
$priceInfo->SKUID=$priceform->input('skuid');
$priceInfo->deviceCategoryId=$priceform->input('dataId');
  $id=$priceInfo->id;
  $priceInfo->save();


  return response()->json([ 
  'SKUID' => $priceInfo->SKUID, 
  'sellingPrice' => $priceInfo->sellingPrice, 
  'id' =>$this->getpriceDetailsId() 
  ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do simply does not work. Just because you sent data of two form in your **1 ajax request** does not mean laravel will interepret it as two request. That is simply not possible.

What you have done in your code is get get data from 3 forms and make a json object from them and sent that json object in **1 get request**. You cannot send **multiple request in 1 request**. This is as fundamental as it gets.

The best way to get the result you want is to accept 1 request object in you controller and parse it to get data from multiple forms that you sent.

Comment: Ok sir.Understood the concept now

Comment: Will you please tell me how to parse it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function as

```
public function finalSubmit(Request $request)
{      
    $var1 = $this->addPriceDetails($request->form1);
    $var2 = $this->addProductDetails($request->form2);
    $var3 = $this->addAdditionalInformation($request->form3);
    //$var4 = $this->addImages($imagesform);//you dont't have $imagesform
    return response()->json(["response"=>"success"]);
}
```

Also change http verb from `GET` to `POST`

```
type: 'POST', //in ajax, it is good send bulk data in post not in get
```

In route

```
Route::post('/dbvalue','priceDetails@finalSubmit');
```

Comment: what is the need of changing it to `POST`

Comment: sir,it shows me `500 Internal server error` in the browser console

Comment: `Method Not Allowed HTTP Exception` on clicking with the browser console link

Comment: It also shows `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\priceDetails::addPriceDetails() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in /var/www/html/AdminPanel/app/Http/Controllers/priceDetails.php on line 868 and defined` in my preview

Comment: `$var1 = $this->addPriceDetails($request->form1);` this is my line number 868

Comment: @nishanthi : make sure you have  change `POST` in all place

Comment: Or better you can try with `/dbvalue` instead of `dbvalue`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154017/discussion-between-user2486-and-nishanthi).